# Remove spring security role

Tags: java, generics, spring-mvc, collections, spring-security

Is there a way to revoke spring security role? Specifically, I want to remove element from `UserDetails.getAuthorities()` object

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities();
authorities.remove(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TO_BE_REMOVED"));
```

This code will be successfully compiled, but will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` when remove is called. The problem is that the standard Authentication implementations ensure that the Collection returned by getAuthorities is non-modifiable (it returns `Collections $UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<E>`).

So what I need is some other way to remove the role, or a way to bypass Collection immutability.

Spring version used: 3.2.2.RELEASE, Spring security version: 3.1.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
public void removeRole(String role){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    List<GrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities =
        auth.getAuthorities().stream()
        .filter(r -> !role.equals(r.getAuthority()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), updatedAuthorities);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use `org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager.updateUser()`.

Comment: Well, I still need to set authorities in UserDetails object

Comment: As a bypass immutability solution, you could put your authorities to `ArrayList`, so they would be copied to new collection and then remove role.